# Angular 10 Unit Testing PrimeNG p-dropdown with 2-Way Data Binding

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, jasmine, primeng

In my Angular 10 app with Jasmine test framework, I need help testing that a PrimeNG `p-dropdown` with 2-way databinding updates my model automatically when an item is selected. In the example below, how would I verify that when an an item is selected, that `selectedCity` (the model in my component) gets updated?

Example Dropdown used in my component:

```
<p-dropdown [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity"></p-dropdown>
```

Dropdown Options:

```
this.cities = [
    { label: 'Select City', value: null },
    { label: 'New York', value: { id: 1, name: 'New York', code: 'NY' } },
    { label: 'Rome', value: { id: 2, name: 'Rome', code: 'RM' } },
    { label: 'London', value: { id: 3, name: 'London', code: 'LDN' } },
    { label: 'Istanbul', value: { id: 4, name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST' } },
    { label: 'Paris', value: { id: 5, name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS' } }
];
```

I tried the following in my component test to no avail, the model is still undefined:

```
it('should populate the model when an item is selected', async(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        const dropdown: Dropdown = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('p-dropdown')).componentInstance;
        dropdown.selectItem(new Event('change'), dropdown.options[1].value);
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(component.selectedCity).toEqual(dropdown.options[1].value);
    });
}));
```

Comment: In general, you should trust that primeNg has tested their own components and that you need not test it for yourself. You only should check your own code that you write. But if you need PrimeNg component for testing, it is best practice to mock and use a spy for your needs

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me.

```
it('Setting Value of the ag via UI and using', async()=>{
    const ag = debugElement.query(By.css('.item-0 .p-element')).componentInstance;
    
    ag.selectItem(new Event('change'),'ag-1');
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(serviceMock.filterCustomers).toBeCalled();

    await expect(firstValueFrom(serviceMock.customers$)).resolves.toEqual(['C-1']);      
  });
```

Comment: There is a missing quote in the test case description.